# iexpress exe with arguments give command line option syntax error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe, iexpress

I'm trying to create a simple exe file that prompts the user with a message via cmd/notepad but the exe file should ignore any other arguments sent to it.

windows shortcut will look like below, I **can not change the shortcut** but can change the exe

[image]

this is the original format of the shortcut

> myexefile.EXE /asn=\testlocation\Software\randomfile.asn  winlog

When creating the exe via iExpress Wizard what should I give for the launch command?

I tied `cmd /c "firstBat.bat"` it didn't work keep getting this error
[image]

really appreciate the help on this